# Tuple treated as single value in group by statement, any workaround?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some calculations roughly looking like this: `trip_count = DF_Trip.groupby([target], as_index=False)['Delivery'].count()`

All my DF could possibly be grouped by `Shop, Route and Driver`. When I enter a single value for target, f.e. `target = 'Route'` it works fine.

But when I want to enter multiple values, f.e. `target = 'Shop', 'Route'` it only works when I enter it directly in the place where the variable is, f.e. `trip_count = DF_Trip.groupby(['Shop', 'Route'], as_index=False)['Delivery'].count()` but when I set the variable to `target = 'Shop', 'Route'`, it gives me a ton of errors.

I've realized from debugging, that `target = 'Shop', 'Route'` is treated as a tuple and read in the pandas.df.groupby documentation, that tuples are treated as a single value. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Use list `target = ['Shop', 'Route']`

Comment: works perfectly, thank you! but now I have an other problem: Later I need to rename the columns, and when I do it that way I have  a "List in List". `DF1.columns = [target, 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'etc']` Is there a way I just rename Col1, Col2, etc and leave the `target` columns untouched?

Comment: Actually, I just realized I can add the two lists. `DF1.columns = target + ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', etc]`

Answer (score 0):

First I had to use a list as suggested by Gennady Kandaurov, and to later rename the columns I just had to add the two lists.

1. `target = ['Shop', 'Route']`
2. `DF1.columns = target + ['static columns']`